# Sort DIVs by attribute with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I am trying to use buttons to sort a number of `DIV` using custom attributes. I was following [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/C2heg/) but cannot make it work with custom attributes. I know there might be a problem with the way I am accessing the attributes, but not sure how to fix it.

My `HTML` is:

```
<button id="opBnt">OP</button>      
<button id="inBnt">IN</button>
<div id="collapsible" class="panel-collapse">                   
    <div id="1" class="superduper" data-sort-op="0.4" data-sort-in="0.1">a</div>
    <div id="2" class="superduper" data-sort-op="0.2" data-sort-in="0.8">b</div>
    <div id="3" class="superduper" data-sort-op="0.3" data-sort-in="0.3">c</div>
</div>
```

And `JS`:

```
var $divs = $("div.superduper");
$('#opBnt').on('click', function () {
    var opOrder = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).getAttribute('data-sort-op') > $(b).getAttribute('data-sort-op');
    });
    $("#collapsible").html(opOrder);
});

$('#inBnt').on('click', function () {   
    var inOrder = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).getAttribute('data-sort-in') > $(b).getAttributel('data-sort-in');
    });
    $("#collapsible").html(inOrder);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vabm/ukxab41m/4/)

Comment: [`return Number($(a).data('sort-op')) > Number($(b).data('sort-op'));`](https://jsfiddle.net/ukxab41m/2/)

Comment: Is data-sort-op a unique attribute? Always an integer?

Comment: in my original code they are always floats, here I used ints to simplify

Comment: Even if it is an integer value, reading it from the data attribute will always return it as a string. So @Tushar’s suggestion still might need to have `parseInt`/`parseFloat` thrown in, to work correctly.

Comment: @CBroe I've used `Number` as in the given example integers are shown. OP should use `parseFloat` as the values are floats.

Comment: I will edit to reflect use of floats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The `sort` function should return `-1, 0, 1` values.
2. You can use the `data` function to access `data-*` attributes.

Check this example:

```js
var $divs = $("div.superduper");
$('#opBnt').on('click', function () {
    var opOrder = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).data('sort-op') < $(b).data('sort-op') ? -1 : 1;
    });
    $("#collapsible").html(opOrder);
});

$('#inBnt').on('click', function () {   
    var inOrder = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).data('sort-in') < $(b).data('sort-in') ? -1 : 1;
    });
    $("#collapsible").html(inOrder);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="opBnt">OP</button>      
<button id="inBnt">IN</button>
<div id="collapsible" class="panel-collapse">                   
    <div id="1" class="superduper" data-sort-op="4" data-sort-in="1">a</div>
    <div id="2" class="superduper" data-sort-op="2" data-sort-in="8">b</div>
    <div id="3" class="superduper" data-sort-op="3" data-sort-in="3">c</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Done. Your code just slightly improved using **.data** method instead of **.getAtrribute**

```js
var $divs = $("div.superduper");
$('#opBnt').on('click', function () {
    var opOrder = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).data('sort-op') > $(b).data('sort-op');
    });
    $("#collapsible").html(opOrder);
});

$('#inBnt').on('click', function () {   
    var inOrder = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).data('sort-in') > $(b).data('sort-in');
    });
    $("#collapsible").html(inOrder);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="opBnt">OP</button>      
<button id="inBnt">IN</button>
<div id="collapsible" class="panel-collapse">                   
    <div id="1" class="superduper" data-sort-op="4" data-sort-in="1">a</div>
    <div id="2" class="superduper" data-sort-op="2" data-sort-in="8">b</div>
    <div id="3" class="superduper" data-sort-op="3" data-sort-in="3">c</div>
</div>
```